# XCode 4.3 Archiving Lock

Tags: xcode, ios5

I am having major problems trying to produce an archive in XCode 4.3. When I connect a device and select Product->Archive, I get a "Build Succeeded" notification, then XCode gives me an infinite spinner and become unresponsive. It does the same thing if I try to go to the "Archives" tab in Organizer. Any idea what might be wrong or how I can further diagnose the problem?

Comment: found the fix... I had my xcode-path messed up. I just did: `sudo xcode-select -switch "/Applications"` and it solved it